# Write a specific text/string into a text file for each file present in a specified folder

Tags: linux, bash, shell, file

I am trying to prepare a txt file containing a specific string of text (X tab Y) per line for each file in a folder matching my search parameter.

So far I've got:

```
find ./directory/*.extension -type f | wc -l
```

This gives me the number of files with *.extension - but I can't find a way to print (X separated by tab Y) on a line equal to the number of files matching *find*.

I.e. for 3 files matching my search, the txt file should contain:

```
X Y
X Y
X Y
```

Sorry if this is too basic, but any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do :

`find ./directory/ -name "*.extension" -type f -exec echo -e "X\tY" \; > yourfile.txt`

This will execute the `echo -e "X\tY"` command for each file found by the find and redirect this ouput to the file `yourfile.txt`

Comment: Thanks, but I'm getting the following error: "find: paths must precede expression: exec"

Comment: @krepsen Your welcome, consider marking the answer if it resolved your problem ;)